# Не работает click в javascript, нужна помощь

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, народ начинаю изучать js, вот есть скритец:

```
  $(document).ready(() =>
            {
                $("#rowPerPage").on("change", () =>
                {
                    var pages = $("#rowPerPage>option:selected").text();
                    //var pages = 15;
                    var form = $("form.search.pull-left");

                    var input = $("<input>").attr(
                            {"type": "",
                             "name": "pages",
                             "id": "pages",
                             "value": pages
                            }
                    );
                    $(input).appendTo(form);
                    document.getElementById("#filtAccept").click();
                });
            });
```

вот форма:

```
 <form class="search pull-left" style="padding-right: 5px;" method="get" name="frm" action="Search">
       <label>Що</label> <input type="text" minlength="3" size="12px" name="osdch" value="${osdch}" id="osdch" align="middle" placeholder="Осд(Що)">

       <label>Куди</label> <input type="text" minlength="3" size="12px" name="osdk" value="${osdk}" id="osdk" align="middle" placeholder="Осд(Куди)">

       <label>Код виробу</label> <input type="text" size="12px" name="kiz" value="${kiz}" id="kiz" align="middle" placeholder="Код виробу">

       <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="1">

       <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="0">



<%      long curTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String svi = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(curTime2);
                                            %>

        <input type="hidden" name="svi" id="svi" value="<%=svi%>">

        <button id="filtAccept" class="btn  btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Виконати фільтр">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>

        </form>
```

И собственно вопрос, почему не срабатывает автоматически кнопка?: `document.getElementById("#filtAccept").click();`

Comment: Потому что у вас ошибка в скрипте. Посмотрите ошибки в консоли.

Comment: В метод `getElementById` ID должен передаваться без `#`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что click - это метод jQuery, а вы пытаетесь с его помощью работать с нативным html элементом, полученным нормальным способом.
Вам нужно либо

```
$("#filtAccept").click();
```

Либо

```
document.getElementById("filtAccept").dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

---

**UP:**
Бес попутал, так натурально можно:

```js
document.getElementById("filtAccept").click();
```

```html
<button id='filtAccept' onclick='console.log(1)'>Button</button>
```

Comment: Неправда, метод `click` есть не только в jQuery: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: сделал  так, так тоже можно ?`document.getElementById("filtAccept").click();`

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Обновил ответ

Comment: Еще можно `document.querySelector("#filtAccept").click()`.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь